# SQL insert values from previous date if specific date information is missing

Tags: sql, datetime, vertica

I have got the following table.

```
date2                     Group    number
2020-28-05 00:00:00         A        55
2020-28-05 00:00:00         B        1.09
2020-28-05 00:00:00         C        1.8
2020-29-05 00:00:00         A        68
2020-29-05 00:00:00         B        1.9
2020-29-05 00:00:00         C        1.19
2020-01-06 00:00:00         A        10
2020-01-06 00:00:00         B        15
2020-01-06 00:00:00         C        0.88
2020-02-06 00:00:00         A        22
2020-02-06 00:00:00         B        15
2020-02-06 00:00:00         C        13
2020-03-06 00:00:00         A        66
2020-03-06 00:00:00         B        88
2020-03-06 00:00:00         C        99
```

As you can see between dates 2020-30-05 and 2020-31-05 are missing in this table. So it is necessary to fill these dates with 2020-29-05 information grouped by GROUP. As a result the final output should be like that:

```
date2                     Group    number
2020-28-05 00:00:00         A        55
2020-28-05 00:00:00         B        1.09
2020-28-05 00:00:00         C        1.8
2020-29-05 00:00:00         A        68
2020-29-05 00:00:00         B        1.9
2020-29-05 00:00:00         C        1.19
2020-30-05 00:00:00         A        68
2020-30-05 00:00:00         B        1.9
2020-30-05 00:00:00         C        1.19
2020-31-05 00:00:00         A        68
2020-31-05 00:00:00         B        1.9
2020-31-05 00:00:00         C        1.19
2020-01-06 00:00:00         A        10
2020-01-06 00:00:00         B        15
2020-01-06 00:00:00         C        0.88
2020-02-06 00:00:00         A        22
2020-02-06 00:00:00         B        15
2020-02-06 00:00:00         C        13
2020-03-06 00:00:00         A        66
2020-03-06 00:00:00         B        88
2020-03-06 00:00:00         C        99
```

I tried to do in the following way:
create a temporary table (table B) with only dates for period 2020-28-05 till 2020-03-06 and then use left merge, thus making these new dates as null (in order to then insert a CASE when null, so fill in last_value). However, it does not work, because when merging I got nulls only for one date (but should be 3 times one date(because of groups). This is only part of the larger dataset, can you help how can I get the necessary output? 
PS I use Vertica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Vertica. And Vertica has the `TIMESERIES` clause, which seems to exactly match with what you need:

Out of a time series - like you have one - with irregular intervals between the rows, or with longer gaps in an otherwise regular time series, it creates a regular time series, with the same interval between each row pair as you specify in the `AS` sub-clause of the `TIMESERIES` clause itself. `TS_FIRST_VALUE()` and `TS_LAST_VALUE()` are functions that rely on that clause and return the right value deduced from the input rows at the generated time stamp. This right value can be obtained `'const'`, that is from the row in the original row set closest to the generated time stamp, or `'linear'`, that is, interpolated from the original row just before and the original row just after the generated timestamp. For your needs, you would use the constant value. See here:

```
WITH
-- your input ....
input(tmstmp,grp,nbr) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','A',55
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','B',1.09
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-28 00:00:00','C',1.8
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','A',68
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','B',1.9
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-05-29 00:00:00','C',1.19
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','A',10
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','B',15
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-01 00:00:00','C',0.88
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','A',22
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','B',15
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-02 00:00:00','C',13
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','A',66
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','B',88
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-06-03 00:00:00','C',99
)
-- real query here ...
SELECT
  ts AS tmstmp
, grp
, TS_FIRST_VALUE(nbr,'const') AS nbr
FROM input
TIMESERIES ts AS '1 DAY' OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY tmstmp)
ORDER BY 1,2
;
-- out        tmstmp        | grp |  nbr  
-- out ---------------------+-----+-------
-- out  2020-05-28 00:00:00 | A   | 55.00
-- out  2020-05-28 00:00:00 | B   |  1.09
-- out  2020-05-28 00:00:00 | C   |  1.80
-- out  2020-05-29 00:00:00 | A   | 68.00
-- out  2020-05-29 00:00:00 | B   |  1.90
-- out  2020-05-29 00:00:00 | C   |  1.19
-- out  2020-05-30 00:00:00 | A   | 68.00
-- out  2020-05-30 00:00:00 | B   |  1.90
-- out  2020-05-30 00:00:00 | C   |  1.19
-- out  2020-05-31 00:00:00 | A   | 68.00
-- out  2020-05-31 00:00:00 | B   |  1.90
-- out  2020-05-31 00:00:00 | C   |  1.19
-- out  2020-06-01 00:00:00 | A   | 10.00
-- out  2020-06-01 00:00:00 | B   | 15.00
-- out  2020-06-01 00:00:00 | C   |  0.88
-- out  2020-06-02 00:00:00 | A   | 22.00
-- out  2020-06-02 00:00:00 | B   | 15.00
-- out  2020-06-02 00:00:00 | C   | 13.00
-- out  2020-06-03 00:00:00 | A   | 66.00
-- out  2020-06-03 00:00:00 | B   | 88.00
```

Comment: Thank you for a help