# Fill data from previous date to next day date if data for specific data is missing and fill only for days Saturday and Sunday

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Table called as **DATA** which will have data for some period. Table Example

```
currency    indicator   Frequency      Date      Value
AED/USD      KN.I1         M        2022-04-15    10
AED/USD      KN.I2         M        2022-04-15    10
AED/USD      KN.I3         M        2022-04-15    10
AED/USD      KN.I4         M        2022-04-15    10
AED/USD      KN.I5         M        2022-04-15    10
AED/USD      KN.I5         M        2022-04-16    15
```

as we can see date '2022-04-15' is Friday and date '2022-04-16' is saturday. I would like to have the same row with the same value of 2022-04-15 for next date if the row is missing or value is null (next date should be **Saturday or Sunday** and date should not cross the current date) . and also it should not isert the row if value is already exist for that date- shown in expected output

The expected output

```
currency    indicator   Frequency   Date       Value
AED/USD     KN.I1          M       2022-04-15   10
AED/USD     KN.I1          M       2022-04-16   10
AED/USD     KN.I2          M       2022-04-15   10
AED/USD     KN.I2          M       2022-04-16   10
AED/USD     KN.I3          M       2022-04-15   10
AED/USD     KN.I3          M       2022-04-16   10
AED/USD     KN.I4          M       2022-04-15   10
AED/USD     KN.I4          M       2022-04-16   10
AED/USD     KN.I5          M       2022-04-15   10
AED/USD     KN.I5          M       2022-04-16   15  -- This row already exists and not to be filled by previous value
```

As we see in output file it has added new rows having the same value to previous date (2022-04-16 is saturday) . current date is 2022-04-16 (just assuming it as current a date) hence it should not add rows for 2022-04-17(Sunday)

I referred this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170940/sql-insert-values-from-previous-date-if-specific-date-information-is-missing) but it looks like not related to my question. Please someone help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to do the data gap filling via a [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) / [GENERATOR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html) pattern:

```
 SELECT row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
    FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
```

and then to value fill values gap with [LAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html)

```
nvl(value, lag(value) ignore nulls over (partition by currency order by date)) as value
```

which becomes:

```
with data(currency,indicator,Frequency,Date,Value) as (
    select * from values
        ('AED/USD', 'KN.I1', 'M', '2022-04-15'::date, 10),
        ('AED/USD', 'KN.I2', 'M', '2022-04-15'::date, 10),
        ('AED/USD', 'KN.I3', 'M', '2022-04-15'::date, 10),
        ('AED/USD', 'KN.I4', 'M', '2022-04-15'::date, 10),
        ('AED/USD', 'KN.I5', 'M', '2022-04-15'::date, 10),
        ('AED/USD', 'KN.I5', 'M', '2022-04-16'::date, 15)
), range as (
    SELECT row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn
        FROM table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 1000))
), mins as ( 
    select currency, indicator, min(date) as min_date
    from data
    group by 1,2
), mix as (
    select m.currency, m.indicator, dateadd(day, r.rn, m.min_date) as day_date
    from mins as m
    join range as r
    qualify day_date <= current_date()
)
select 
    m.currency, 
    m.indicator,
    m.day_date as date,
    nvl(d.value, lag(d.value) ignore nulls over (partition by m.currency, m.indicator order by m.day_date)) as value
from mix as m
left join data as d
    on m.currency = d.currency and m.indicator = d.indicator and d.date = m.day_date
order by 1,2,3;
```

| CURRENCY | INDICATOR | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AED/USD | KN.I1 | 2022-04-15 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I1 | 2022-04-16 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I1 | 2022-04-17 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I1 | 2022-04-18 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I1 | 2022-04-19 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I2 | 2022-04-15 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I2 | 2022-04-16 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I2 | 2022-04-17 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I2 | 2022-04-18 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I2 | 2022-04-19 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I3 | 2022-04-15 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I3 | 2022-04-16 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I3 | 2022-04-17 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I3 | 2022-04-18 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I3 | 2022-04-19 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I4 | 2022-04-15 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I4 | 2022-04-16 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I4 | 2022-04-17 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I4 | 2022-04-18 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I4 | 2022-04-19 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I5 | 2022-04-15 | 10 |
| AED/USD | KN.I5 | 2022-04-16 | 15 |
| AED/USD | KN.I5 | 2022-04-17 | 15 |
| AED/USD | KN.I5 | 2022-04-18 | 15 |
| AED/USD | KN.I5 | 2022-04-19 | 15 |